# Galaxy S8 Proximity Sensor

Tags: proximity-sensor, samsung-galaxy-s-8

So I just got my galaxy S8, and whenever i'm listening to a voice note it outputs through bottom (loud) the speaker. However, if I bring my phone close to my ear so only I can listen to the voice note through the stop speaker, it still plays on the bottom speaker.

My previous phone had this feature, so every time there was sound playing through the bottom speaker and I brought the phone next to my ear, the output of the sound changed. Does the galaxy s8 has this feature? I've tried to look for it everywhere but I haven't found anything yet.